# How do I identify the breaker a non-working outlet is on?

Tags: receptacle, circuit-breaker

I have an electrical outlet that doesn’t work and needs to be changed. Is there anyway to figure out what circuit breaker is attached to the outlet to avoid switching off the main power to the whole house?

Comment: Do you have a voltage tester?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:  You don't really know why that receptacle doesn't work, and the simplest thing is to just shut off the main.

If it's a bad receptacle as you are assuming, you can't test it reliably outside the box.  That puts you in a bit of a catch 22;  you can't figure out which branch circuit breaker the receptacle is on, so you can't shut off the branch circuit breaker so it's safe to go inside the box.

If the problem is with the neutral connection, a non-contact voltage in the ungrounded slot in the receptacle will indicate voltage.  If that's the case, you could flip breakers until that goes out to determine which breaker that receptacle is on.  It's not wise to put too much confidence in a non-contact tester, so you'd want to proceed with great caution opening that box.

In fact it's probably better to just turn off the main.  And it is still wise to proceed with caution, checking and double checking to verify no presence of voltage as you go.

Answer (score 1):

You can't, really. You can try locating the breaker for nearby outlets, but this doesn't guarantee the right one will be found. Instead, begin your troubleshooting with the proper tools.

Get yourself an inexpensive multi-meter and check the wires in the outlet box for power using the 200v AC setting. It's usually safe to work if you check voltage between hot and neutral, or hot/neutral and ground and don't see values of around 120 or higher.

You can remove the outlet mounting screws and pull it out carefully, then begin checking voltages on the screws before removing wires.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with a **three-light tester** and determine if the malfunctioning receptacle has any voltage.  If the three-light test indicates the hot is still working, you'll be able to use a **circuit breaker finder** to identify which breaker supplies the receptacle.

Use a **non-contact voltage tester** before handling any of the wiring inside the receptacle's box, even if you think that wiring isn't live.

Comment: Most consumer grade circuit finders require a functional receptacle to work the pro grade will work with or without power but they cost 10x the consumer grade.